# Finding Hypersurfaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have the following question. I want to find all the hypersurfaces $z=z(x,y)$ such that satisfies the equation:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-e^{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=e^{y}z
x$$
and contains the curve 
$$x=e^t\text{,}\hspace{0.5cm}y=t\text{,}\hspace{0.5cm}z=t\text{.}$$
I am truly lost.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-e^{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=xe^{y}z
$$

is given by

$$
z(x,y) = e^x \left(e^{-y}\right)^{x+\sinh (y)-\cosh (y)} \phi (x+\sinh (y)-\cosh (y))
$$

and if it contains the cited curve we need to verify

$$
t = e^{e^t} \left(e^{-t}\right)^{2 \sinh (t)} \phi (2 \sinh (t))
$$

concluding that

$$
\phi(u) = e^{-e^{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)}} \left(e^{-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)}\right)^{-u} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)
$$

so the sought surface is

$$
z(x,y) = \left(e^{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-y}-x\right)\right)}\right)^{e^{-y}-x} e^{x-e^{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} (x+\sinh
   (y)-\cosh (y))\right)}} \left(e^{-y}\right)^{x+\sinh (y)-\cosh (y)} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} (x+\sinh (y)-\cosh (y))\right)
$$

Follows a plot showing in yellow the surface $z(x,y)$ and in red the curve $z(e^t, t)$

[image]